# SSL javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert: unrecognized_name Accept this

Tags: java, ssl

I want to accept all certificates for all sites but I get from one site unrecognized_name. How can i accept or pass it so that i can get the content of this site?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends, do you want to use an HttpClient that accepts all certificates?

Comment: i want actualy to download a file and i got this. HttpUrlConnection that is what i use

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-fix-ssl-error-javaxnetsslsslprotocolexception-handshake-alert-unrecognizedname-websphere-application-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to accept all certificates for all sites but I get from one site unrecognized_name.

This is not a certificate problem and thus you cannot fix it by accepting all certificates (which is usually a very bad idea anyway). You get this kind of error if you access a server which requires [SNI (Server Name Indication)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) without SNI  or with the wrong name in the SNI extension. Fix is accordingly to use SNI with the correct name.

If SNI is supported depends on your Java version and might also depend on the version of the library you use to access the site.

Comment: how can i acces the site then i use the latest java version

Comment: @NoiZeR: the latest Java supports SNI. If the library you use supports it check by searching for the library name in connection with SNI. And again, it might just be that you already use SNI but with the wrong name.